# Login con arreglo en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola estoy haciendo un login con arreglos en android studio pero cada vez que quiero pasar a una nueva actividad no pasa nada

```
 public EditText user, contra;

public String usuarios [] = {"lexar", "carito", "juan", "amanda"};
public String contraseña [] = {"hola", "1234", "casa", "moviles"};
public String tipo [] = {"Administrador", "Soporte", "Cliente", "Tecnico"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsuario);
    contra = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etContra);
}

public void Entrar(View view){
    int i = 0;
    String etUser = user.getText().toString();
    String etContra = contra.getText().toString();

    if (etUser == "lexar" && etContra == contraseña[i]){
        Intent next = new Intent(this, pantalla1.class);
        startActivity(next);
    }
}
```

El metodo Entrar ya esta ne el onClick del boton de entrar.

El XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUsuario"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/usuario"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etContra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/contra"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etUsuario"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etUsuario" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEntrar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
        android:onClick="Entrar"
        android:text="@string/btnEntrar"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btnSalir"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnSalir" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSalir"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:onClick="Salir"
        android:text="@string/btnSalir"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/etContra"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etContra" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="@string/titulo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: si no pasa nada es porque la condicion `if (etUser == "lexar" && etContra == contraseña[i])` esta dando **false**

Comment: puedes dejar ver el xml de esos `EditText`

Comment: ya escribi el el diseño en XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema es que si tu usuario no es "lexar" con su contraseña "Hola" no va a cambiar de actividad, es decir no funcionaria para el resto de los usuarios ya que no comparas con el resto solo con "lexar", de la siguiente manera puedes comparar en todo tu arreglo con sus respectivas contraseñas:

```
String etUser = user.getText().toString();
String etPassword = contra.getText().toString();
boolean usuarioEncontrado = false;
for(int i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++){
    if (usuarios[i].equals(etUser)){
        if (contraseña[i].equals(etPassword)){
            // cambiar de actividad
        }else {
            usuarioEncontrado = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (!usuarioEncontrado){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Usuario incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Recomendación**

Deberías considerar usar una base de datos como sqlite para guardar la información de los usuario.

Espero te sea de utilidad saludos.

Comment: Gracias! me funciono tu metodo!

Comment: Excelente @EduardoNoyola cualquier cosa aquí andamos saludos.